# Is there PHP constant equivalent to PHP_OS_FAMILY (for PHP < 7.2)?

Tags: php

Is there PHP constant or function equivalent to the constant PHP_OS_FAMILY for PHP version lower than 7.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best option for PHP < 7.2:

```
echo php_uname('s');
```